# can anybody help me find what is the js error i get in explorer 7 and 8?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If i run the link in ieTester, in ie7 pops up a js error and the site doens't work, if i try  ie8 i don't get a pop msg but it doesn't work neither. It says: Line 219 Char 1 Error expected identifier, string or number Code 0

in here: link off - issues was the answer below

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ie does not function when it encounters a comma `,` before a `}`. Remove it.

```
infoBox.css({
        "visibility": "hidden",
        "height": "auto",    //<--- Remove this comma
});
```